# Regex to Validate a Decimal field to Hours and Minute Format

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a requirement to Validate a Decimal Field on an enterprise application to Hours and Minute Format.

so for example  7.30 is 7 hrs 30 minutes

9.55 is 9 hours 55minutes

10.80 .....this should not be accepted.

23.59 is the maximum.

I tried the sample code.

```js
function ValidateTotalHours() {
  var totalhours = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_totalhours").getValue();

  if (!/^([0-23]).([0-5][0-9])$/.test(totalhours)) {
    Xrm.Utility.alertDialog("Total Hours Format is invalid");

  }

}
```

I tried validating with https://regex101.com/ before proceeding but it seems my Regex expression is incorrect.

Any ideas on the correct implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern is incorrect:

- `[0-23]` equals `[0123]`
- `.` needs to be escaped. `\.` otherwise it will match any character except line break

What you need is: `^([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-3])\.([0-5][0-9])$`

```js
const pattern = /^([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-3])\.([0-5][0-9])$/;

const times = ['24.00', '23.60', '22.59', '04.05', '4.05', '23.02', '15.25', '24.59'];

times.forEach(time => {
  console.log(`${time}: ${pattern.test(time)}`);
});
```

Comment: Perfect Thanks, not used to Regex...but is it possible to specify a format like of string in 8:20 AM??  So the regex could be 8:20 AM or PM .. i tried this ^([0-1]?[0-1]|1[0-1]):([0-5][0-9]) ([AM]|[PM])$   else the answer is correct

Comment: The square brackets `[]` aren't doing what you think they do. If you wanted an optional AM/PM, you'd do something like `( [AP]M)?`

Answer (score 1):

The `[0-23]` in the RegEx:

```
/^([0-23]).([0-5][0-9])$/
```

is actually specifying:

```
[0123]
```

You want something like this:

```
/^(2[0-3]|[01]?[0-9])\.[0-5][0-9]$/
```

Comment: Thanks Yimin , I definitely need to take a look at Regex, but am more of a Dynamics CRM Developer, how can I get the full regex validation for a string filed.     8:30 AM ..so 8:30 AM or PM so the first letters shoud be 1-11 representing the time and then the : the the next is minutes 1-59..its 01- 59 because it has to have 2 digits and not one and then a space the after you have AM or PM ..i know this is wrong ^([0-1]?[0-1]|1[0-1]):([0-5][0-9]) ([AM]|[PM])$ . regards.